# Appropriate "Reference Request" Question - List of Launch Scrubs?

Tags: discussion

I asked about a list of launch scrubs [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20537231#20537231), and @briligg suggested that the question might be appropriate for the main site. I wanted to check here to be sure first, though.

Generally, questions that are simply requesting pointers to outside resources or lists are frowned upon in the StackExchange network. So I was a bit surprised to find that, as @briligg pointed out, [reference-request](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) is a tag that's actually used here on Space Exploration.

---

The question I'd like to ask essentially boils down to: "Where can I find a list of rocket launches to date, including scrubbed launch attempts (and the reason for each scrub)?"

> For example, I'm interested in seeing a list that includes the
>   following for each launch:
>
> - Rocket used.
> - Rocket configuration used.
> - First planned launch date.
> - Actual successful launch date.
> - Mission accomplished? (Payload delivered to intended orbit/body. Return payloads, if any, brought back successfully.)
> - Number of scrubs.
> - Category/Reason for each scrub.
>
>   - Weather
>   - Technical (Rocket Problem, Payload Problem, Range Problem, Other)

Comment: ...yeah, this meta room is not the most frequented place in the world. Go ahead and ask your question on the site. It is probably the best way to get an answer to this question as well. ;)

Comment: @briligg Wow. This has been viewed 24 times in 13 days...

Comment: @raptortech97 yeah... it would seem space exploration enthusiasts aren't the meta type. Also we've gotten pretty used to TildalWave handling these things right away, and he's otherwise occupied at the moment.